# Enter Does Not Work For Submit, ASP.NET Page Refreshes and Doesn't Search

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with an ASP.NET site with a C# back end.  There is a .Master page where the  tag is, and other search pages on the site will search when you hit enter after filling out the form.  However we have one page that has a few text boxes and when you hit enter to search, it appears to just refresh and reload the page without searching.  In order to search you have to hit the search button (which is an igtxt:WebImageButton ).  All of the solutions I have found to this issue so far involve people using javascript to call some kind of function on submit.  As far as I know there is no javascript being called when you hit the search button, it is all in the C# code.  Once again I find myself searching SO and other sites for an answer but none of the solutions seem to fit my situation.  The form tag is as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

The web image buttons call a btn_SearchClick function that runs the search code. But since the form is started in the .Master file I can't edit that as it would effect all other pages as well.  Is there any way to have enter call the btn_SearchClick from the form without having to put it in the form tag?  I'm not sure what would've changed to cause this behavior on one page and none of the others.

Comment: Browsers are really weird when it comes to hitting ENTER. I forget the rules, but it's something to do with how many input controls are on the page, and it will sometimes submit your form but not click your submit button - in most web frameworks, this is fine, but in the ASP.NET WebForms world, submitting a form but not using the button results in the button click handler not firing, which is where I'm sure your code is. I'd recommend finding some javascript that handles the ENTER key, and attaching it wherever you need on the form.

Comment: @Justin Could you post the small testable code so that we can replicate the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", 
                   "doClick('" + btnSearch.ClientID + "',event)");
}
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
    function doClick(buttonName,e)
    {
        //the purpose of this function is to allow the enter key to 
        //point to the correct button to click.
        var key;

         if(window.event)
              key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
         else
              key = e.which;     //firefox

        if (key == 13)
        {
            //Get the button the user wants to have clicked
            var btn = document.getElementById(buttonName);
            if (btn != null)
            { //If we find the button click it
                btn.click();
                event.keyCode = 0
            }
        }
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

or u can use default button.it's work while  cursor's in this box

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Form.DefaultButton = this.btnSubmit.UniqueID;
        }
```

Comment: Where does that first snippet end up going?  In the .cs code?

Comment: Thanks rush, that seemed to do the trick although I would like to use this as a temporary fix as I try to find the real issue with this page.  I see that you've specified Firefox and IE, but can I assume that this will work for Chrome as well?  I'm in the process of also formatting the CSS file for all browsers since in Chrome and Firefox some of the formatting is a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

Add some [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to control the Enter key behavior on your textbox. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#<%=txtTextbox.ClientID%>').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#<%=btn_SearchClick.ClientID%>').click();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I just tried to implement this code but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  Going to do some more testing and see if I can get it working.